# Cartesian product of words in a line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm having an input file name 'a' which contains data as below:

```
BHARAT,SELXG,SAAB|ABCI
BHARAT,HONEY,HIRO,ABBS|XYZQ
```

My expected output is:

```
BHARAT|ABCI
SELXG|ABCI
SAAB|ABCI
BHARAT|XYZQ
HONEY|XYZQ
HIRO|XYZQ
ABBS|XYZQ
```

I have used: `perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' a` - which is not giving the expected output.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Your title is not addressing your problem. Also, I think you need a script to make such change since it is much more complex than simply replacing comma with new line

Comment: You are correct Mostafa... A script will definitely me as i have list that contains more that 1M records as mentioned above test list.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged your question `perl`, here's a couple of ways to do it in that language:

1. split and join

   ```
   $ perl -F'\|' -alne 'print join "|", $_, $F[1] for split ",", $F[0]' a
   BHARAT|ABCI
   SELXG|ABCI
   SAAB|ABCI
   BHARAT|XYZQ
   HONEY|XYZQ
   HIRO|XYZQ
   ABBS|XYZQ
   ```
2. split and map

   ```
   $ perl -F'\|' -alne 'print for map { "$_|$F[1]" } split ",", $F[0]' a
   BHARAT|ABCI
   SELXG|ABCI
   SAAB|ABCI
   BHARAT|XYZQ
   HONEY|XYZQ
   HIRO|XYZQ
   ABBS|XYZQ
   ```

Comment: Great!! got the result as expected... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved in many ways. Here is one one liner using `awk`

```
cat a | awk -F"[,|]" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"|"$NF}'
```

**In terminal**,

```
$ cat a
BHARAT,SELXG,SAAB|ABCI
BHARAT,HONEY,HIRO,ABBS|XYZQ

$ cat a | awk -F"[,|]" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i"|"$NF}'
BHARAT|ABCI
SELXG|ABCI
SAAB|ABCI
BHARAT|XYZQ
HONEY|XYZQ
HIRO|XYZQ
ABBS|XYZQ
```

**How it works:**

- Reads a line with both `,` and `|` as delimiter.
- Prints each column in a row followed by last column in that row with `|` as  delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for share this code. However it is not returning any output.

Comment: @VishwaRanjan sorry to know that. I tested it before posting, it works. It should work for you as well. There may be any other issue(s). I think your job done in other answers, if you still think you should dig the reason why this did not work for you, first check if you `gawk` installed. feel free to reply, we may find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

#### A python alternative:

In a one- liner:

```
python3 -c "for l in open('f'): d = l.strip().split('|');[print('|'.join([s, d[1]])) for s in d[0].split(',')]"
```

Where `'f'` is the path to your file, in (single) quotes.

Output:

```
BHARAT|ABCI
SELXG|ABCI
SAAB|ABCI
BHARAT|XYZQ
HONEY|XYZQ
HIRO|XYZQ
ABBS|XYZQ
```

#### Or more readable:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

# open the file
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
    # remove spaces from the line(s), split by "|"
    d = l.strip().split('|')
    # list the first part of the line, join each of the items with the second part of the line
    [print('|'.join([s, d[1]])) for s in d[0].split(',')]
```

*To use*

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `reorganize.py`
2. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/reorganize.py /path/to/file_a
   ```

#### Explanation:

The script:

- Opens the file, reads it per line:

  ```py
  for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
  ```
- splits the line by the delimiter `|`, removes the trailing `\n`

  ```py
  d = l.strip().split('|')
  ```
- splits the first part by the delimiter "," listing its items: `d[0].split(',')`, and joining each of the items with the last part of the line: `print('|'.join([s, d[1]]))`:

  ```
  [print('|'.join([s, d[1]])) for s in d[0].split(',')]
  ```